# MySQL find value in a separated hyphen list

Tags: mysql, pdo, bind

I have a user id that I would like to find if this id existed in a separated list with hyphen, using a bind method:

I have **2 issues**:

**1- The correct SQL query,**

**2- How to bind the value.**

Table structure:

```
mysql> SELECT dash_cat_id, dash_users_cats FROM dash_cats;
+-------------+-----------------+
| dash_cat_id | dash_users_cats |
+-------------+-----------------+
|           1 | 2               |
|           2 | 1,2             |
|           3 | 1               |
|           4 | 2               |
|           5 | 1,2,3           |
|           6 | 1,2,3           |
|           7 | 1,2,3           |
|           8 | 1,2,3           |
+-------------+-----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

$userID = 2; // this might be changed to 1 OR 3, it depends of the user
```

Then I would like to retrieve all dash_users_cats that the userID is 2 as an example;

I used this query, but it seems to be wrong:

```
 mysql> SELECT dash_cat_id, REPLACE(dash_users_cats, '-', ',') as dashRep from dash_cats WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, dash_users_cats);
 +-------------+---------+
 | dash_cat_id | dashRep |
 +-------------+---------+
 |           1 | 2       |
 |           4 | 2       |
 +-------------+---------+
 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT:**

**I changed the hyphen with the comma**

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Comment: So, if I use a comma separated, how can be the query then?

Comment: You might have misunderstood... Do **not** use strings with separated lists **at all**, regardless of the separator character, comma or dash or whatever...

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and decide.

Comment: So I should use an array like this [1,2,3]?

Comment: There are no arrays in MySQL. And even if there were: No, don't use it. Use a linking table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on this, I can't sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your tables by storing single user_cat value against each user_id. Refer to @Bill Karwin's answer. However, you can still make your current solution work by replacing comma with hyphen in the `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT dash_cat_id,
REPLACE(dash_users_cats, '-', ',') as dashRep
FROM dash_cats
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, REPLACE(dash_users_cats, '-', ','))
```

Answer (score 2):

In a relational database, there are no "lists" or "arrays". Use a set of rows, one value per row in the given column.

```
mysql> SELECT dash_cat_id, dash_users_cats FROM dash_cats;
+-------------+-----------------+
| dash_cat_id | dash_user_id    |
+-------------+-----------------+
|           1 | 2               |
|           2 | 1               |
|           2 | 2               |
|           3 | 1               |
|           4 | 2               |
|           5 | 1               |
|           5 | 2               |
|           5 | 3               |
|           6 | 1               |
|           6 | 2               |
|           6 | 3               |
|           7 | 1               |
|           7 | 2               |
|           7 | 3               |
|           8 | 1               |
|           8 | 2               |
|           8 | 3               |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

Now you can search for a specific user easily:

```
SELECT * FROM dash_cats WHERE dash_user_id = 2;
```